# how to use secret variables from Azure variable group in pipeline?

Tags: docker, variables, azure-pipelines

We have the following varables defined in a variable group in Azure:

```
  "DATABASE": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "smdb_all"
  },
  "HOSTNAME": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "localhost"
  },
  "PASSWORD": {
    "isSecret": true,
    "value": null
  },
  "ROOT_PASSWORD": {
    "isSecret": true,
    "value": null
  },
  "USER": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "IntegrationTest"
  }
}
```

Then this group variables are read in an Azure pipeline:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    # Get variables from group
    $be_common=az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id <some_id> --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
    echo "$be_common"
    $user = $be_common.USER.value
    $root_password = $be_common.ROOT_PASSWORD.value
    $database = $be_common.DATABASE.value
    $password = $be_common.PASSWORD.value
    echo "Get single values"
    echo "$user"
    echo "$database"
    echo "$password"
    echo "$root_password"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task_user]$user"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task_database]$database"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task_password]$password"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task_root_password]$root_password"
    echo "End"

  env: 
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
  displayName: 'Get backend common variables'
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login to ACR
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: ${{ parameters.dockerRegistryServiceConnection }}

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image to container registry
  inputs:
    command: build
    repository: ${{ parameters.imageRepository }}
    dockerfile: ${{ parameters.dockerfilePath }}
    buildContext: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    containerRegistry: ${{ parameters.dockerRegistryServiceConnection }}
    tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    arguments: '--build-arg CURRENT_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(task_root_password) --build-arg CURRENT_USER=$(task_user) --build-arg CURRENT_PASSWORD=$(password) --build-arg CURRENT_DATABASE=$(task_database)'
```

And the problem is, that as the root password, and password are secret variables, after the conversions the "task_root_password" and "task_password" are empty strings - this is the log  of the pipeline (the pipeline builds and pushes a mariadb docker image):

```
createdAt:2023-02-01T15:04:26Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MARIADB_DATABASE=smdb_all; layerId:sh
createdAt:2023-02-01T15:04:25Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MARIADB_PASSWORD=; la
createdAt:2023-02-01T15:04:24Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MARIADB_USER=IntegrationTest; layerId:sh
createdAt:2023-02-01T15:04:23Z; layerSize:0B; createdBy:/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=; la
```

What should i do in order the actual values of the password and the root_password to be passed as arguments of the build?

Comment: Why are you grabbing the variable group via the cli? Is there a reason why you cannot just reference the variable group with the "- group: <your group>" directly in the pipeline?

Comment: The reason is that i did not know this approach. I used it. Now i use directly the variables in this line arguments: '--build-arg CURRENT_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(SMDB_ROOT_PASSWORD) --build-arg CURRENT_USER=$(SMDB_USER) --build-arg CURRENT_PASSWORD=$(SMDB_PASSWORD) --build-arg CURRENT_DATABASE=$(SMDB_DATABASE)', but the problems stays the same.

Comment: Can you update your topic with the new code? Secret variables are hidden by default in the logs as a security measure, even though they can be used in commands. Moreover, in you post it says that the secret had value null, have you verified that an actual value is added?

Comment: Actually i was wrong - the code was working fine and the problem was at another place. Currently i have only one issue - how to pass a secret variable to a python code, which uses the maria db docker image, mentioned into this question. I posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75324508/how-to-use-secret-variables-from-azure-variable-group-in-a-script-part-of-a-pipe